# Python Concurrent Futures for Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I have one dataframe of couple thousands of rows

`input_df`

```
case_id api_param   stat
1        data1      1
2        data2      0
1        data3      0
4        data4      0
1        data5      1
```

I do a `groupBy(case_id)` and get:

```
  case_id    1      2       3  
      1     data1  data3  data5          
      2     data2  nan    nan   
      4     data4  nan    nan
```

Now suppose that for each `case_id` that I would like to modify the date value in the api_param column for all the case_id where stat == 0. => modify data2, data3, data4.
To do so I decide to choose a new data within k data points of the prior data and call the API to check that the data is valid;

ie: url = **https:// example..com/over/there?name=api_param[i]**  with api_param == data2 +k data pnt for example for case_id ==2 above.
if the API response is 200 then I am able to overwrite the old value in the `input_df`.

Now I may have thousands of such cases in my file, and each case has many datapoints to change.
Let say I have 300 cases which each have 100 dates to modify

And therefore using the Python **requests** API would be very slow. I would like to use concurrent.futures; How could I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this functions

```
def check_api_call(count, dates):
    length = dates.values.__len__()
    executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    for i in range(length):
        date = dates.values[i]
        pool = executor.submit(task_api, date)
        response = pool.result()
        while not response:
            count = count + 1
            day_value = count * 7
            td = pd.to_timedelta(day_value, unit='d')
            delta_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") + td
            new_date = delta_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            pool = executor.submit(task_api, new_date)
            response = pool.result()
            if not response:
                continue
            dates.values[i] = new_date
    return True, dates

def task_api(date):
    url = "https:// example..com/over/there?name=" + date
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from datetime import timedelta

# get dates with stat=0
dates = input_df[input_df['stat']==0]['api_param']
# get urls, add 7 days to date (assuming date is already datetime.datetime)
urls = dates.apply(lambda date_obj: 'https:// example..com/over/there?name=%s' % str(date_obj+timedelta(days=7))).tolist()

with ThreadPool(10) as pool:
    results = pool.map(request.get, urls)

# add request status to input_df
input_df['request_status'] = 0
input_df.loc[input_df['stat']==0, 'request_status'] = [x.status_code for x in results]

# update dates
input_df.loc[(input_df['stat']==0) & (input_df['request_status']==200), 'api_params'] = input_df.loc[(input_df['stat']==0) & (input_df['request_status']==200), 'api_params'].apply(lambda date_obj: date_obj+timdelta(days=7))
```